# Recreational Math Problem about unknown amount of rotating vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, recreational-mathematics

I created this recreational math problem that where it looks like solver doesn't have enough information to solve it. This kind of algebra problem I haven't really seen in the wild before, as you don't know the number of variables that you are given. Along the way of solving, there are several mathematical gems that you come across, (at least through the method that I solved it). I deleted a post of this exact problem with a physics narrative, but I figured that math by itself is more appropriate here.

Please have fun solving!

### Problem

---

A countable amount of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ rotate about the origin at their own constant speeds. Each vector $\vec{v}$ has a magnitude that varies in time $t$ described by $|\vec{v}(t)| = a \cdot b ^ t$, for their own values of $a,b\in \mathbb R_{>0}$. The sum of the vectors at time $t$ is notated by $\vec{u}(t)$.

There's a time $t_c$ where each vector equals $\vec{v_c}$ and:

1. $|\vec{u}(t_c-1)| = 1+\frac{1}{|\vec{v_c}|}$.
2. $\vec{u}(t_c+1) = -\vec{v_c}$.
3. $\vec{u}(t_c+2) = 3 \vec{v_c}$.
4. $\vec{u}(t_c+n) = \vec{u}(t_c + n - 2) - \vec{u}(t_c + n - 1), \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{>2}$

What is the numerical value of $|\vec{v_c}|$?

Comment: @bobeyt6 They are allowed.  It is called a *self-answer* problem.  However, the original poster is expected to post an answer, either directly in the posting, or in a separate answer box.  Also, the original poster may choose to use the MathJax (hide) facility, which is facilitated via `>!` on the LHS of each paragraph.

Comment: As I mentioned with the now-deleted version of your question, you should show your solution (using the simple `>!` method or posting an answer, but not making readers follow that complicated RSA-hash procedure). After all, a reader might consider composing, formatting, and/or illustrating a formal answer to be a waste of their time —especially if they may have simply duplicated your own approach— but they'd probably still like to check their work. Also, seeing whether their solution improves-upon yours might encourage posting an answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your advice. I respectfully understand your reasoning for providing and answer; I don't want to waste anyone's time including yours. This math problem is for people who enjoy solving problems recreationally and want to explain how they solved it. My wish is that if I provide the answer, someone won't reverse engineer the problem and then accept it before anyone else takes the journey to solve it (we all know how the internet is). I know,  SHA256 hashing looks like overkill. It just seemed like good way to prevent this while ensuring an answer exists.

Comment: Following these thoughts, I would like to know if the solution I have is not the only one. This solution can bias the technique for solving for others. Its may not the best way to solve, which is what I am very interested to learn.

Comment: When someone has their solution posted, I am more than happy to post what I have :)

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of 
[Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted twice...

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I have most of a solution, but it requires that one of the signs in the puzzle is incorrect. Which is interesting but problematic. (Specifically, I'd need each vector to be equal to $-v_c$ at time $0$.)

Comment: What do you mean by "countable" ? Shouldn't the adjective be instead : "finite" (countable means that, possibly, there is an infinity of vectors) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for taking an interest here! Yeah, I felt this problem seemed to out of place for the puzzling stack exchange after looking at type of problems on it; I think this one is too mathsy and I would only get redirected back to math stackexchange by comments.

Comment: @JeanMarie You make a good observation, however countable is not mistakenly used here.

Comment: @EricSnyder Thank you for also taking interest! Just for clarity, did you mean that you need each vector must be equal to $-v_c$ at time $t_c$ or is it when t=0? I think I know what you mean but I just want to be sure.

Comment: @MassimilianoCutugno Technically at time $t_c$, calling it time zero is simpler. The series as presented rather demands a *spoiler* at that time, but the posed problem implies it should be the negation of that. (Of course, negating everything doesn't help the situation, alas.) Edit:. Actually typing that out does lead to a different possible idea, adding something I might not have accounted for.

Comment: @EricSnyder I just negated rules 2 and 3. This should fix your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex plane is basically ismorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, right? Let's set this in the complex plane. Then each of the vectors can be defined as $a \cdot b^t \cdot  \exp(i\tau k(t-t_c) + i\tau m)$, where $k$ and $m$ depend on the period and phase. Also, I'm setting $t_c = 0$ to save on a bunch of annoying $(t-t_c)$ factors like we just saw.

> Equations 2, 3, and 4 are $\vec v_c$ times the definition of the alternating Lucas sequence, i.e., $(1, -3, 4, -7, 11, -18, \cdots)$. That implies that $\vec u(0) = -2\vec v_c$, and $\vec u(-1) = -\vec v_c$. Why this implication?
>
> Because the three equations generate a recurrence, we can find an explicit closed form for the values of the magnitude over time. The characteristic polynomial is $x^2 +x-1$, which has the two roots $r_1, r_2 = -\phi, \phi -1 = 1/\phi$. (Here $\phi$ is the golden ratio, i.e. $\phi = \frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$.) Then the closed form is
>
>  $$u(t) = ar_1^{t} + br_2^{t}$$
>
> Then, we can solve this system in order to determine $a$ and $b$:
>
>  $$\begin{cases} u(1) = v_c = a(-\phi)^1 + b\phi^{-1} \\ u(2) = -3 v_c = a(-\phi)^2 + b\phi^{-2} \end{cases} \\ \\ \implies a = b = -v_c \implies \color{green}{u(t) = -v_c(-\phi)^{t} - v_c\phi^{-t}} $$
>
> We still need to fit with equation 1, but that's actually really easy. What number is equal to its own reciprocal plus one? Why $\phi$ of course! Since we have absolute values in 1, it could also be $-\phi$, but we'll assume not for the moment. This suggests we have two vectors:
>
> $$\vec v_1 = \phi \cdot \phi^t \exp \left(\frac{i\tau t + i\tau}{2} \right) = \phi^{(t+1)} \exp \left(\frac{i\tau t+i\tau }{2}\right)$$
>
> $$\vec v_2 = \phi \cdot\phi^{-t} \exp \left(\frac{i\tau}{2} \right) = \phi^{(-t+1)} \exp\left(\frac{i\tau}{2}\right)$$
>
> Note that $\vec v_1$ rotates once per $2$ time units, $\vec v_2$ is stationary, and at $t=0$, both are pointed along the negative real axis. These two vectors account for all of the constraints... except one. We're told that at $t=0$, *all* of the vectors are equal to $\vec v_c$, and at $t=1$, their *sum* is $\vec v_c$. Yet it's clear that at $t=0$ they both have value $-\phi$, but at $t=1$ their sum has value $\phi$.
>
> But here's the thing: any linear combination of vectors which produces the series after $t=1$ must be equivalent to the combination given above (or the same thing, with $\vec v_1$ turning clockwise rather than counterclockwise). Hence, the combination must produce a value of $u(0) = -2\phi$ rather than $u(0) = 2\phi$, as implied by the question.

I look forward to seeing what the correcting factor is that I've missed.

> Oh! The actual answer to the question is, of course, $\phi$, and I don't think it depends on the recurrence at all; only on equation 1.

Comment: Isa, thank you for the edit, and now I see how to do it if, for some reason, I need to in the future. :)

Comment: I negated rules 2 and 3 so this answer is correct. Nice Job!

Comment: The recurrence relation guarantees that the solution has only one value. The proof for this I'll leave open for anyone ambitious.

Comment: Is there a way to correct the steps of this solution based off the negations made to the original problem? Sorry for the hassle!